# Uncheck box after copiying data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script to copiying data from column B in sheet1 when box in column E is checked:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "MM-dd-yyyy | HH:mm:ss");
  
  var cell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1" && cell.getColumn()==5 && cell.getValue() == true){
    
    var row=cell.getRow();
    var range=sheet1.getRange(row,2,1,1);
    range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow()+1),1));
    sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow()),2).setValue(d);
          }
}
```

I need to edit this code so to unchek boxes after copiying data, also i want this code to work just in the range (B3:B12) not in the all of column B in sheet1.

I tried some changing but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function runs where row is from 3 to 12 and column 5 is set to TRUE in Sheet1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.range.rowStart < 13 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var sheet2 = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy | HH:mm:ss");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow() + 1), 1));
    sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow()), 2).setValue(d);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet.

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: It works without error and i did not supply the event object, i just run the script and it works

Comment: I don't think so it would have failed on the first line you must have another onEdit that you wrote perhaps